# Method that count minutes from post publishing

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm writing small social web application using Django. So I need to count minutes from post publishing (e.g like it looks in Twitter)

[image]

I tried to do something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # post model fields

    date = models.DateTimeField('Date')

    @property
    def publish_date(self):
        if self.date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)):
            return f'{timezone.now().minute - self.date.minute} minutes ago'
        else:
            return self.date
```

And use it into HTML like this: `<span id="post_date">{{ p.publish_date }}</span>`, where `p` is post instance

But sometimes it's returns negative values (like in example below)

[image]

So how can I correctly realize this?

Comment: Please show the definition of the field `date` on your `Post` model.

Comment: look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat added

Comment: @h4cktivist how do you set the value of this field? Please show the code where you set this fields value.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat date sets to `timezone.now()`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

Comment: I guess `naturaltime` is that what i need, thank you all

Comment: @h4cktivist you hadn't considered that times could be within an hour from each other yet be in different hours. Consider `4:20` to be when you post and `5:10` when you check this which will give you `-10` as the result (datetime math is not very simple), and as suggested above the timesince filter or the humanize module is what you should be using. :)

Comment: You should use `timedelta` when returning because it is not necessarily at the exact same hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, you can use the [`naturaltime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime) template filter.

```html
<span id="post_date">{{ p.date | naturaltime}}</span>
```

or, also the [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince),

```html
<span id="post_date">{{ p.date | timesince }}</span>
```